# PHP\HTML dynamic dropdown listing with auto filed population from PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, html, postgresql, gis

I have updated this script. The dynamic dropdown portion of the script requirement has been achieved with contributions from the good members of this forum. Now I am working on getting some of the fields on the form to auto populate when an item is selected from the dropdown list. For instance if I select pipeno and wallthickiness from my dropdown, I would like to have the corresponding tuples of  DJoint, pipeno2,  Heatno1 and heatno 2 on the record to automatically populate their various fields in the form from the database
The field I am looking to auto-populate are the ones Im echoing in the php scipt but I think something is not very right with my script as I keep getting this error on the last line of the script. I will really appreciate some contributions and help with this issue

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   C:\Users\imasha\Documents\My Web Sites\Personal Site1\dropdown2.php
>   on line 63

Here is my updated script

```
        <?php
         // Php Code to connect to postgresqldatabase
         include ("connection.php");

        $query = 'select * from fieldtally order by pipeno asc'; 
        $result = pg_query($db_handle,$query); 
        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
        {

       // Creates Arrays to use in dropdowns
            $pipeno_array[] = $row[0];
            $wallthickness_array[] = $row[1];
        } 

        // Declare dropdown functions for the HTML form
        function dropdown($field_name, $num){

        // Creates the Dropdown
            echo "<select name=\"".$field_name."\" id=\"".$field_name.$num."\"\n";
            echo "<option value=\"\"> --- Select --- </option>\n";
            // Chooses which array to use for Dropdown options
            global $pipeno_array, $wallthickness_array;
            $name_array = ($field_name == 'pipeno') ? $pipeno_array : $wallthickness_array;
            // Creates the Dropdown options based off the array above
            foreach($name_array as $k){
                echo "<option value=\"$k\">$k</option> \n"; }
            // Ends the Dropdown
             echo "</select>\n"; 
             if($field_name == 'pipeno'){
                $wallthickness = 'wallthickness';
                echo $formValue->DJNo($DJno);
                echo $formValue->Heatno1($pipeweight);
                echo $formValue->pipeno2($pipeno2);
                echo $formValue->Heatno2($pipegrade);
        }
        ?>

        <html>
        <head><title>UG Pipeline Fiedl Data Capture</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p></p>
        <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">
        <table width="600" cellpadding= "10" cellspacing="1" border="2">
        <tr align="center" valign="top">
        <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#64b1ff">
        <h3>Input Field Tally Information</h3>
        Select Pipe No:<?php dropdown('pipeno', 1); ?>  Select Wall Thickness:<?php dropdown('wallthickness', 1); ?><br /><br />

     DJ No:<input type="text" name="jointno" value="<?php $DJno = "jointno"; echo $formValue->DJNo($DJno);?>"> 

    HeatNo1: <input type="text" name="pipeweight" value="<?php $pipeweight = "pipeweight"; echo $formValue->Heatno1($pipeweight); ?>"><br><br>

    pipeno2: <input type="text" name="loadtally" value="<?php $pipeno2 = "loadtally"; echo $formValue->pipeno2($pipeno2);?>"> 

    HeatNo2: <input type="text" name="pipeweight" value="<?php $pipeweight = "pipegrade"; echo $formValue->Heatno2($pipegrade); ?>"><br><br>

    Input Serial No: <input type="text" name="serialno"><br><br> 

    Input measured Length: <input type="text" name="measuredlength"><br><br>

    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    </td></tr></table>
    </form>

<p>
<form action="fieldbend.php" method="post">
<table width="600" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" border="2">
<tr align="center" valign="top">
<td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#ff9d9d">
<h3>Input Field Bend Information</h3>
Select Pipe No:<?php dropdown('pipeno', 2); ?>  Select Wall Thickness:<?php dropdown('wallthickness', 2); ?><br /><br />
Input Measured Distance: <input type="text" name="measureddistance"><br /><br /> Input Bend Angle: <input type="text" name="benddegree"><br><br>
Input Bend Type: <input type="text" name="bendtype"><br><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</td></tr></table>
</form></P>

<p>
<form action="apptally.php" method="post">
<table width="600" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="2">
<tr align="center" valign="top">
<td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#66CC66">
<h3>Input App. Tally Information</h3>
 Input Type: <input type="text" name="type">   Input Serial No: <input type="text" name="serialno"><br><br>
Input Reference ID: <input type="text" name="referenceid"><br><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</td></tr></table>
</form></P>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Shade, since your original question was answered, and this is a new issue, you should do this as a new question, not by editing your first question. First, most users will not see your question, because it has an answer. Second, with a new question/answer both you and the person that helps solve your issue will get rep points, which neither of you will receive by answering this edit. I will be happy to help again, once you post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice a few issues in your code.

The first one, pointed out by Mauricio, is that your `<options></options>` are not inside your `<select name="education"></select>` tags. Also why is your select name `education`, when the options are `$row['pipeno']`, and you are getting `$_POST['pipeno']`?

The second issue is when you are echoing the `<options></options>`.

```
//<option> value="<?=$row["pipeno"]; ?>"><?=$row["pipeno"]; ?></option>
        print ("<option> $row[0]</option>");
```

You are commenting out the `<option>` opening tag, the `value` is outside the `<option>` tag as you already closed it, and it looks like you are echoing each option twice with `<option value="<?=$row["pipeno"]; ?>"><?=$row["pipeno"]; ?></option>` & `print ("<option> $row[0]</option>");`

**EDIT**
this is updated to match your edited code in your question

After looking over this again, I think your problem is how you are creating your dropdown. Try putting this at the top, as a function, and then you just call it later wherever you need it. You can then specify if the dropdown is for `pipeno` or `wallthickness` and then just specify what # of dropdown, so it can create a unique `id`.

Try changing the code to-

```
<?php
 $PGHOST = "localhost:25376";
 $PGDATABASE = "Pipeline";
 $PGUSER = "postgres";
 $PGPASSWORD = "Casa2009";
 $PGPORT = 5432;
 $db_handle = pg_connect("dbname=$PGDATABASE user=$PGUSER password=$PGPASSWORD");
 if ($db_handle) {
 echo 'Connection attempt succeeded.';
 } else {
 echo 'Connection attempt failed.';
 }

$query = 'select * from fieldtally order by pipeno asc '; 
$result = pg_query($db_handle,$query); 
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
{
    // Creates Arrays to use in dropdowns
    $pipeno_array[] = $row[0];
    $wallthickness_array[] = $row[1];
} 

 // This function creates dropdowns that can be used in your forms
function dropdown($field_name, $num){
    // Creates the Dropdown
    echo "<select name=\"".$field_name."\" id=\"".$field_name.$num."\"\n";
    echo "<option value=\"\"> --- Select --- </option>\n";
    // Chooses which array to use for Dropdown options
    global $pipeno_array, $wallthickness_array;
    $name_array = ($field_name == 'pipeno') ? $pipeno_array : $wallthickness_array;
    // Creates the Dropdown options based off the array above
    foreach($name_array as $k){
        echo "<option value=\"$k\">$k</option>\n"; }
    // Ends the Dropdown
    echo "</select>\n";
}
?>

<html>
<head><title>UG Pipeline Fiedl Data Capture</title>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">
<table width="600" cellpadding= "10" cellspacing="1" border="2">
<tr align="center" valign="top">
<td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#64b1ff">
<h3>Input Field Tally Information</h3>
Select Pipe No:<?php dropdown('pipeno', 1); ?>  Select Wall Thickness:<?php dropdown('wallthickness', 1); ?><br /><br />
Input Joint No: <input type="text" name="jointno"> Input measured Length: <input type="text" name="measuredlength"><br><br>
Input Serial No: <input type="text" name="serialno"><br><br> 
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</td></tr></table></form> 

<p>
<form action="fieldbend.php" method="post">
<table width="600" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" border="2">
<tr align="center" valign="top">
<td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#ff9d9d">
<h3>Input Field Bend Information</h3>
Select Pipe No:<?php dropdown('pipeno', 2); ?>  Select Wall Thickness:<?php dropdown('wallthickness', 2); ?><br /><br />
Input Measured Distance: <input type="text" name="measureddistance">  Input Bend Angle: <input type="text" name="benddegree"><br><br>
Input Bend Type: <input type="text" name="bendtype"><br><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</td></tr></table>
</form></P>

<p>
<form action="apptally.php" method="post">
<table width="600" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="2">
<tr align="center" valign="top">
<td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#66CC66">
<h3>Input App. Tally Information</h3>
 Input Type: <input type="text" name="type">   Input Serial No: <input type="text" name="serialno"><br><br>
Input Reference ID: <input type="text" name="referenceid"><br><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</td></tr></table>
</form></P>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my sample `fieldtally` table -

[image: <code>fieldtally</code> table]

Here is what the forms look like - 
[image: html forms]

note: I used select size="3" to show multiple lines for this image, but left it as standard 1 row in the code above.

Comment: I tried this but Im getting this errors -  Notice: Undefined index: pipeno in C:\Users\iegbulefu\Documents\My Web Sites\Personal Site1\dropdown2.php on line 38. and it completely removes the wallthickness field from the form. which is this line -   echo "<option value=\"".$row['pipeno']."\">".$row['pipeno']."</option>\n";

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code to fix the errors. `Undefined index: pipeno` is because you are using `pg_fetch_row()` so I should have used `$row[0]` instead of `$row['pipeno']`. The `wallthickness` field did not show because I left out the closing `?>` tag before the `</select>` closing tag. Make these changes and let me know if it fixes the errors.

Comment: Hi Sean, I have made the necessary modification but it is still behaving the same way.

Comment: Hi Sean, I have made the necessary modification but it is still behaving the same way. The Wall Thickness and the Pipeno fields are both supposed to be dropdown and on the same form, it should also be above the submit tab as the users is expected to scroll throgh the two fields, select the pipeno and corresponding wall thickness and then enter data into 'jointno','measured length', and the serialno and then press the submit tab for the data to be pushed into the database. when i moved the Wallthickness field to the place below the php closing tag, it displays outside the form.

Comment: You have more things you need to correct then. (1) you have`</form>` before `<form>` - `<p></form></P><form action="fieldtally.php" method="post">`, (2) 'Wall Thickness should be a dropdown', but you posted it as a text box - `Select Wall Thickness: <input type="text" name="wallthickness">`. (3) 'it should be above the submit tab', but you don't show a 'submit tab' in the form or the other fields ('jointno','measured length','serialno'), so I don't know how to help you move them. Also, I find it interesting that you are creating your dropdowns from your previously posted rows in `fieldtally`.

Comment: Thank you very much Sean for taking your time to study this my script. I cant believe I made such dummy mistakes and could not see them. I have made all the corrections you pointed out here and I noticed a good improvement on the srunning of the script, but I am yet to get the data to populate the dropdown .

Comment: I am working on it now. I just want to bring in all the php script for posting the information and for dropdown select into the form and see how it goes. Please dont get weary in helping me! I am determined to get it right.

Comment: Hi Sean, I have made some changes on the script and have been here looking at it for hours to figure out why it is not populating but i have not be able to identify any issue with the code but there has been no success yet

Comment: Shade, I have updated my answer with another option. The new code gets the `pipeno` and `wallthickness` values, saves them to an array, and then using a function puts those arrays into dropdowns. Then you can reuse that dropdown in each of your forms that you have by calling the function  - ie. `dropdown('pipeno', 1);` or `dropdown('wallthickness', 2);`, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: ooooh! my Goooddddd! Sean! Thank you very much for taking your time to help me out with this, I managed to get my dropdown working but only on one field, with the help of your script here which worked perfectly well, I now have the two dropdown fields working. I have just one more problem and that is to get some of the fields to autopopulate when a pipeno is selected. For instance, using the form above I would like to get the joint number to autopopulate once a pineno is selected. I will post my sript above for your preview please. Thanks a  lot

Comment: Please  I noticed that when I run the script including my own little one i did before. The script is not able to load the data into the database. it gives me the error      Connection attempt succeeded. "Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: null value in column "pipeno" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, 0.386, 500, 55, AUGUST). in C:\Users\ifu\Documents\My Web Sites\Personal Site1\fieldbend.php on line 24 Error with query: ERROR: null value in column "pipeno" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, 0.386, 500, 55, AUGUST)."

Answer (score 0):

and its here:

```
Select Pipe No: <select name="education"> </select>  Select Wall Thickness: <input type="text" name="wallthickness"><br><br>
```

You are openning the tag select and closing in the same line, and after you are putting the elements. To solve that, correct this lines:

Change:

```
Select Pipe No: <select name="education"> </select>  Select Wall Thickness: <input type="text" name="wallthickness"><br><br>
```

to:

```
Select Wall Thickness: <input type="text" name="wallthickness"><br><br>
Select Pipe No: <select name="education">
```

and close select tag before close body like this:

```
</select>
</body>
```

Here you are putting the elements in the tag select. Try that

Comment: Hi Mauricio, Thanks for your suggestion,I tried it but it did not make much difference, and was not able to resolve the issue.